# compiling fortran 77 code with ifort : libg2c missing

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77

I am compiling some `fortran 77` code with the `ifort` 2013 compiler. The code requires linking to libg2c, but this library is missing. where can I find it? I am working on a remote computer cluster, is there a way to install this library only locally?

Comment: ifort will not work with libg2c.  If you have legacy non-standard function calls, look up the ifort ifport library.  It's time to make your old code work with a current compiler (gfortran is good also).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libg2c is a library used by the obsolete g77 compiler. If the reference is in a makefile you found, just remove it. The "ifort" command should be able to provide the necessary libraries.